# How to set priorities in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

Trying to scrape webpages and I need to set priorities in order to scrape them in order.  Right now it wants to scrape all the page 1s of each url then all the page 2s and so on.  But I need it to scrape all the pages of url 1 and all the pages of url 2 and so on.  I have been trying to use priorities to do that by setting the first url equal to the highest priority, which would be the number of urls in the csv file.  But it is not working, mainly because I cannot decrement the priority value, because it is in a for loop so every time it enter the loop it resets priorities to the original number, so its the same each time so they all have the same priority.  How can I get the priorities working correctly in order to scrape the urls in the order I want.

SplashSpider.py

```
class MySpider(Spider):

    # Name of Spider
    name = 'splash_spider'
    # getting all the url + ip address + useragent pairs then request them
    def start_requests(self):


        # get the file path of the csv file that contains the pairs from the settings.py
        with open(self.settings["PROXY_CSV_FILE"], mode="r") as csv_file:
           # requests is a list of dictionaries like this -> {url: str, ua: str, ip: str}
            requests = process_csv(csv_file)
            for i, req in enumerate(requests):
                x = len(requests) - i  # <- check here
                # Return needed url with set delay of 3 seconds
                yield SplashRequest(url=req["url"], callback=self.parse, args={"wait": 3},
                        # Pair with user agent specified in csv file
                        headers={"User-Agent": req["ua"]},
                        # Sets splash_url to whatever the current proxy that goes with current URL  is instead of actual splash url
                        splash_url = req["ip"],
                        priority = x,
                        meta={'priority': x}
                        )
```

**UPDATE #1**

```
 # Scraping function that will scrape URLs for specified information
    def parse(self, response):
        # Initialize item to function GameItem located in items.py, will be called multiple times
        item = GameItem()
        # Initialize saved_name
        saved_name = ""
        # Extract card category from URL using html code from website that identifies the category.  Will be outputted before rest of data
        item["Category"] = response.css("span.titletext::text").get()
        # For loop to loop through HTML code until all necessary data has been scraped
        for game in response.css("tr[class^=deckdbbody]"):
            # Initialize saved_name to the extracted card name
            saved_name  = game.css("a.card_popup::text").get() or saved_name
            # Now call item and set equal to saved_name and strip leading '\n' from output
            item["Card_Name"] = saved_name.strip()
            # Check to see if output is null, in the case that there are two different conditions for one card
            if item["Card_Name"] != None:
                # If not null than store value in saved_name
                saved_name = item["Card_Name"].strip()
            # If null then set null value to previous card name since if there is a null value you should have the same card name twice
            else:
                item["Card_Name"] = saved_name
            # Call item again in order to extract the condition, stock, and price using the corresponding html code from the website
            item["Condition"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_7 a::text").get()
            item["Stock"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_8::text").get()
            item["Price"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_9::text").get()
            if item["Price"] == None:
                item["Price"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_9 span[style*='color:red']::text").get()

            # Return values
            yield item


        priority = response.meta['priority']
        # Finds next page button
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(., "- Next>>")]/@href').get()
        # If it exists and there is a next page enter if statement
        if next_page is not None:
            # Go to next page
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse, priority=priority, meta={'priority': priority})
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
2019-06-13 15:16:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.starcitygames.com/catalog/category/1014?&start=50> (referer: http://www.starcitygames.com/catalog/category/Visions)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/usr/home/north/scrapy_splash/scrapy_javascript/scrapy_javascript/spiders/SplashSpider.py", line 104, in parse
    priority = response.meta['priority']
KeyError: 'priority'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change them through the array, it is better to do something like this:

```
   for i, req in enumerate(requests):
        x = len(requests) - i  # <- check here

        # Return needed url with set delay of 3 seconds
        yield SplashRequest(url=req["url"], callback=self.parse, args={"wait": 3},
                # Pair with user agent specified in csv file
                headers={"User-Agent": req["ua"]},
                # Sets splash_url to whatever the current proxy that goes with current URL  is instead of actual splash url
                splash_url = req["ip"],
                priority = x,
                meta={'priority': x}  # <- check here!!
                )
```

And don't forget to use, for example, meta to pass current priority (I don't remember is it possible to get it from response or not) to pass it to each children request.

UPDATE:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        # I skip you logic here
        priority = response.meta['priority']
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(., "- Next>>")]/@href').get()
        # If it exists and there is a next page enter if statement
        if next_page is not None:
            # Go to next page
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse, priority=priority, meta={'priority': priority})
```

Comment: That fixed the decrement problem I was having but it is still not outputting the data in order.  It it changed up a little bit now it outputs the first link of data in its entirety, which is only one page, and then for the second and third link it will output page 1 of one then page 1 of the other and continue to alternate until like 2 which is has less pages is done then it continues to scrape link 3 along with the last link until both of them are done.  So its different but its still not working correctly.

Comment: It basically seems like it wants to do two links at a time in stead of one

Comment: Could it have something to do with my settings.py file?  I updated my question and it is now included.

Comment: Did you set same priorities in your `parse` function also? You need to do it. Same as in parent request.

Comment: I been trying to do that but still new to python and I have been struggling with accessing that data, since I am in a separate function.  Is there a way to access the priority data from my start_requests function inside my parse function?

Comment: I've updated my answer with code for `parse` function. Check carefully that also we set `meta` in `start_requests`.

Comment: I think I am doing everything right but it still it scraping 2 links at once going back and forth until done.  Now though after it scrapes like 3 pages it get an error.  I added error message to my question plus I updated my code to match the changes I have made.

Comment: Please, read my update carefully, do you see changes in `response.follow` in `parse`? Do you see `meta` key in `start_requests`?

Comment: I noticed that I did miss the update in response.follow so I fixed that.  I copy.pasted exactly what you put just to make sure I did not miss anything else.  No more errors, but it still did not fix my problem.  It is still outputting it out of order.  Again scraping two URLs at a time instead of one.

Comment: What do you mean by two urls instead of one? Try to set `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` to 1: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html

Comment: I already have it set to 1.  And what I mean is it will scrape page 1 or URL 1 than page 1 or URL 2 than page 2 of URL 1 and so on.  Once the URL with less pages is done it moves on to the next one while still finishing the URL that has more pages. And it continues to alternate between one URL and the other.  I hope that made sense.  It is kinda hard to explain.